# SQL - how to select only those rows up to a certain row by rownumber

Tags: sql, database

I'm having difficulty constructing a SQL query for loading a file into a database.

Let's say my file looks like this:

```
col1  col2        col3 col4
a     b           c    d
e     f           g    h
end   null        null null
no    interesting data here
not   interested  in   this
bla   bla         bla  bla
```

I want to select ONLY the rows up to the 'end' row. So:

```
col1  col2        col3 col4
a     b           c    d
e     f           g    h
```

The end-row and thereafter are not interesting for my application. The end row is at a different row number for each file we need to load. So I can't use a counter or a TOP statement for this.

How would I go about this?

I suspect I'd need to take care of this in the WHERE clause as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE rownumber < endrownumber
```

Where I'm stuck is the following:

1. how to find the rownumber where col1 = 'end' (as the endrownumber)
2. how to *only* select those rows where the rownumber < endrownumber
3. Is this possible to achieve with a sub-query within the where clause?

Thanks!

T

Comment: You mention this is a file. I suppose you are inserting it into a database? How exactly are you reading the file? (hint: when you hit the row with "end", just stop)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get the result you're looking for:

```
WITH view_1 AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            ORDER BY
                col_1
        ) AS row_num,
        col_1,
        col_2,
        col_3,
        col_4
    FROM
        your_table
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    view_1
WHERE
    row_num < (
        SELECT
            row_num
        FROM
            view_1
        WHERE
            col_1 = 'end'
    );
```

I have created a view which will give each row a row number and will appear as a new column.

The view is then queried just below to check what the above rownumber is for col_1 which = 'end'.

It will then only bring through the rows which are less than it.

I was using Oracle to do all of the above and works as expected.